# Disable selection and itemInvoke event for a particular item in the listview

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I have a listview. By default, all items have `itemInvoke` and `single-selection` enabled. But now, I would like to disable `selection` and `itemInvoke` (both event and animation) for **one particular item** with id "disableMe". Is there a way to do it? Or is it possible to disable the event for the whole group (not the whole listview).?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question because I happened to figure it out today. Please advice if you have better solution for this issue.

In Metro Style Application, selection in ListView control can usually be triggered by `Right-Click` with mouse or by a small 'drag'/'swipe' with touch. To disable touch selection, you need to overwrite the `MSPointerDown` event handler for that particular item. To disable 'Right-Click' selection, you need to overwrite the `oncontextmenu` event for that particular item.

If you are creating `itemTemplate` in `Javascript`:

```
function listViewItemTemplate(item) {
    // data has boolean properties called 'doNotSelectMe' and 'doNotInvokeMe'
    var data = item.data._value;

    var itemElement = document.createElement('div');
    var itemElement.id = 'testElement';

    if (data.doNotSelectMe) {
        // disable mouse selection
        itemElement.oncontextmenu = function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); };
        // disable touch selection
        itemElement.addEventListener('MSPointerDown', function (e) {
                                          e.stopPropagation();
                                     });
    }

    if (data.doNotInvokeMe) {
        //disable item invoke event
        itemElement.onclick = function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); };
    }

    return {element: itemElement}

}
```

Comment: So I'm selecting the template dynamically:

`element = document.querySelector(".inputTemplate");`

and then soon thereafter rendering it to a new container:

`var container = document.createElement("div");`
`element.winControl.render(currentItem.data, container);`

and then later testing if the item is a certain type and doing what you wrote, worked the first time. thanks